# Line shape doesn't appear in Android API 21

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to make a line shape in `Android`. It works fine in all `Android` versions except `API` 21.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">

<size
    android:height="3px"
    android:width="10px" />
<stroke android:color="@color/brightPurple" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a non-zero stroke width.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <size
        android:height="3px"
        android:width="10px" />
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/brightPurple"
        android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```